# Bootstrap 4 - Dropdown w/ Toggleable-XL

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

So I've been using Bootstrap 4 w/ Understrap for my latest theme development, and I'm running across a strange bug with the dropdown feature. It seems when using a navbar that is toggleable-xl, a dropdown will resize the entire when opened.

Here is an example of the issue: http://codeply.com/go/7IOdz8L2RS

You can see that by changing toggleable-xl to toggleable-sm it fixes the issue. The reason I have to use toggleable-xl is due to wanting to remove the collapsing feature of the navbar. I know that I could simply not use the navbar, but I would like to keep the styling if possible. Any ideas on why the drop down does this? or how I can accomplish this navbar without creating that issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue for this:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/22058

A workaround is:

```
.navbar-toggleable-xl .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/cd92P7PAgE

Comment: Thanks! was thinking there might have been an open issue regarding it, but wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something simple. Also, side question, are you Skelly on Codeply? if so, thanks for all the Bootstrap 4 Snippets, they are SO helpful!!